# How do I change the content of a WinForms label from the Program.cs main method?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a start-up routine in my main method that checks to make sure there is content in a .txt file.

```
 FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(DataDir);
 if (fInfo.Length < 64)
 {
     //Do stuff here if file is not long enough
 }
```

I want to be able to make a label on my WinForms app display some text and I want to grey out some controls, but I can't seem to find a way to reference said label/controls, or any object in my form for that matter. I am a beginner, and I am struggling to figure this out.

Comment: where is this code written?

Comment: You need a reference to the form object, there you can manipulate all its public controls. Another option is to run this check before and pass the info on the form's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to work with your `Form` object from the `Main()` method you would need to pass in an object instead of using the `new` keyword.

This is what you normally see (Visual Studio produces this code).

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

What you can do to work with the form object.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 myForm = new Form1(); //create the object here
        //you can work with the form here
        Application.Run(myForm); //pass in the form
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure he can work with the form, but the `Main` method should have no idea what's inside the form. That's called "separation of concerns". It allows the form to change its appearance in any way it likes without `Main` needing to know about the change.

Comment: I completely agree. I was just offering another solution to the issue.

Comment: It's another solution, but it's a bad solution and there's no reason to go there.

Answer (score 1):

In your form, declare a `bool` field and initialize it in the form's constructor:

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    private bool _fileNotLongEnough;

    public MyForm(bool fileNotLongEnough) {
         _fileNotLongEnough = fileNotLongEnough;}
```

Now later in the form, you can use the value of this field to decide whether to do things.

In your `Main` method, you are already constructing the form. This time, pass it a `bool`:

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(DataDir);
Application.Run(new MyForm(fInfo.Length < 64));
```

Comment: Actually it is not good for a form to have a parameterized constructors. The windows form designer will not work properly. Or you keep the parameterless constructor and overload it.

Comment: Yes, keep the parameterless constructor. Or add a public property that you set immediately after construction.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  can you elaborate more on this solution with the public property?